# r square or parameter p value, what's more important?

Tags: sas, regression, linear-regression, p-value

I'm a university student who is learning data science.
I've developed a regression model which is like alchol=num*?+age*?.
The sas program result came out like below. But I'm concerned because r square value is too close to 0. parameter p-value are below 0.05 and F value too, but r square value is different from other values. Can I know what's the reason of low r-square value? And is this model not significant because of r square value?
Thank you for reading this question.
[image]

Comment: This is a good moment for you to do a scatter plot together with your regression and see what your regression model did to your data. That should, hopefully, give you a lot of information as to why your statistics are the way they are. You are correct that the R squared value is very low. The `Pr > |t|` tells you that all three covariates (intercept, num and age) are all significant at a 0.05 rejection level.

Comment: Bear in mind that you are asking a question here on stackoverflow.com and not stats.stackexchange.com. You may have done your analysis in SAS but questions about R squared and P value significance are more statistical questions than SAS related.

Comment: okay thank you..! I didn't know about stats.stackexchange.com. From now on I should use the platform to ask about statics. Thank you for your advice!!